# Proof Verification/Help: Convergence of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Question: Let ${(x_n)} $ be a sequence of real numbers and $x \neq 0$. $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n =x$ iff:
$\lim_{n \to \infty}(x_n-x)/(x+x_n)=0$

Proof:

"$\implies$"

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n =x$. This implies that $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that"

$|x_n - x|<\epsilon$  $\forall n\geq N$

$ \implies |(x_n -x) - 0|<\epsilon$ $ \forall n\geq N$

$\implies$ $\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n -x)=0$

Now consider $|x +x_n|$

Claim: $\lim_{n \to \infty} |x+x_n| =2x$

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given

$|(x+x_n)-2x| = |x_n -x| < \epsilon$ $\forall n\geq N$ for some$N \in \mathbb{N}$

Then: $\lim_{n \to \infty}(x_n-x)/(x+x_n)=0$

= ${\lim_{n \to \infty}(x_n-x)}/\lim_{n \to \infty}(x+x_n)=0/2x =0$

"$\Longleftarrow$"

Can anyone please verify the forward implication of the proof? Also, I'm unable to see how to go about the backward implication. Can anyone please guide/give hint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your forward implication is correct.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(x_n-x)/(x+x_n)=0$$

Let $$(x_n-x)/(x+x_n)=y_n$$

$$(x_n-x)=(x+x_x)y_n$$

Assuming that $(x+x_x)$ is bounded,

$$lim _{n\to \infty} (x_n-x)= lim _{n\to \infty}(x+x_x)y_n =0$$

$$lim _{n\to \infty} (x_n-x)\implies lim _{n\to \infty} x_n=x$$

Comment: Also, why did you assume that $(x+x_n)$ is bounded?

Comment: Otherwise we have a case of  $0\times \infty $

Comment: Hello, can you please have a look at this question of mine and verify if the proof is correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, your forward implication is correct.